# Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)

Tags: c, xcode, pointers

In C, do I need to have a nullability type specifier for each pointer? I had just created an XCode project (C) and tried to run a function:

```
char * someFunction(void);
```

and I got the warning

```
Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)
```

I didn't know a nullability type specifier was required for pointers in C?

Just saying, everything runs fine. Its just there are lots of warnings (lots of functions) and it is bugging me a little.

Comment: Notice that all the "nullability specifiers" start with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter? Such symbols are *reserved* in all scopes for the compiler itself. Which means it's a non-portable and compiler-specific extension to the C language.

Comment: Does this mean I *must* have a nullability specifier?

Comment: It's not part of standard C. And it's a warning, not an error. And it's probably a warning you can disable.  So there's no "must" here, it's only a friendly remainder by the compiler to add it, probably for some extra compile-time checks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Do not advise people to ignore things you do not understand. OP is building in an Apple environment. Nullability information is used for interacting with Swift. Their project may not be configured as a pure C project, in which case disabling warnings and ignoring the issue could cause some things not to function as desired.